# Отсутствует оператор ">", соответствующий этим операндам const Money > double

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Проблема в том, что, когда пытаюсь сравнить в конструкторе класса деньги с числом, то выдаёт такую ошибку, хотя этот самый оператор присутствует. (Account.cpp)

Money.h

```
#pragma once
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Money
{
private:
    unsigned long rouble;
    unsigned char penny;
public:
    //Сравнение с числом
    bool operator==(const double &val);
    bool operator>=(const double &val);
    bool operator<=(const double &val);
    bool operator !=(const double &val);
    bool operator <(const double &val);
    bool operator >(const double &val);
};
```

Money.cpp

```
bool Money::operator==(const double &val)
{
    return ((rouble == (int)val));
}

bool Money::operator>=(const double &val)
{
    return ((rouble >= (int)val));
}

bool Money::operator<=(const double &val)
{
    return ((rouble <= (int)val));
}

bool Money::operator !=(const double &val)
{
    return ((rouble != (int)val));
}

bool Money::operator >(const double &val)
{
    return ((rouble > (int)val));
}

bool Money::operator <(const double &val)
{
    return ((rouble < (int)val));
}
```

Account.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "Money.h"
class Account
{
private:
    std::string surname; //Фамилия аккаунта
    double percent; //процент начисления
    int number; //номер счета
    Money Amount; //сумма
public:
    Account();
    Account(const std::string&,const double&,const int&,const Money&);
};
```

Account.cpp

```
#include "Account.h"
#include "Money.h"

Account::Account() 
    :surname("surname"), percent(0.0), number(0), Amount(0.0) {}

Account::Account(const std::string &surname, const double &percent, const int &number, const Money& Amount)
{
    if (surname.length() > 0) 
    { 
        this->surname = surname;
        if (percent > 0 && percent < 100)
        {
            this->percent = percent;
            if (number > 0)
            {
                this->number = number;
                if (Amount > 0.0)
                          ^^^
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw "Объект не создан!\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В этом вызове объект имеет тип `Money const &` а метод `operator <` работает с объектами без `const` квалификатора. Соответственно надо сделать так, чтобы `operator <` работад с объектами, имеющими `const` квалификатор:

```
bool operator >(const double &val) const
```

А еще лучше вынести этот оператор в свободную функцию:

```
bool operator >(Money const & money, double const val)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы объявили

```
bool operator >(const double &val);
```

как **изменяющий** значение сравниваемого объекта. А сравнивать пытаетесь константный объект.

Не думаю, что вы реально хотите что-то менять в объекте при сравнении, так что объявите операторы как константные:

```
bool operator >(const double &val) const;
```